# Вывод картинки по надписи из textbox на picturebox

Tags: c#

Введя нужный месяц в textbox1 нужно, чтобы по нажатию на зеленую кнопку в окне picturebox1 появилась нужная картинка. Картинки уже лежат в папке проекта нужен конкретно код который свяжет: button, textbox и picturebox между собой.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Укажите используемый графический фреймворк: WinForms, WPF, Xamarin, что-то ещё?

Answer (score 1):

Можно создать словарь, сопоставив название месяца с именем файла изображения. Как-то так:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string,string>();
dict.Add("Ноябрь", "november.jpeg");
...
```

Далее в обработчике события Click у кнопки устанавливаете BackgroundImage у PictureBox на нужное изображение. Примерно так:

```
pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(dict[textBox1.Text]);
```